# Infinite Circles

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, circles, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Trying to solve for t: $$\left(o_x+v_x\cdot t - \left\lfloor \frac{o_x+v_x\cdot t}{d}+\frac12\right\rfloor\cdot d\right)^2+\left(o_y+v_y\cdot t - \left\lfloor \frac{o_y+v_y\cdot t}{d}+\frac12\right\rfloor\cdot d\right)^2=r^2$$
This will allow me to see when a line intersects any circle that has a radius of *r* and is separated by distance *d*. *o* is the origin of the line, and *v* is its direction
You might still not know what this is doing, allow me to explain. Imagin you were on a sheet of grid paper, inside each grid there is a circle, and no matter where you are on this sheet you would be in a grid, depending on what grid you are in you could find the circle that is closest to you (being the circle in the grid you are in)

Comment: This looks like an ordinary quadratic equation in $t$ to me.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a floor function?  What's it doing here?  I don't understand what is "separated by distance $d$" from what?

Comment: @saulspatz it is a floor function, it is being used to get an idea for the center of the circle, but my real interest is the equation in terms of _t_

Comment: A basic principle of Mathematics is that we never use notations that haven't been defined beforehand.  Making retro-engineering to guess what you mean by these notations and what is your overall need ("solve for $t$ for doing what ?...)... Help people to help you...

Comment: @JohnPorter Please explain what your terms mean.

Comment: _This will allow me to see when a line intersects any circle that has a radius of r and is separated by distance d. o is the origin of the line, and v is it's direction_ what more is needed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need for the floor function (either from the post or from the OP's comment above)

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks for your comment, there was a mistake in my equation that I said I was trying to solve, it is fixed now.

Comment: @saulspatz This equation seems to describe the intersection of a straight line and the union of all the circles of radius $r$ centered at points of the form $(md,nd)$ with integers $m$ and $n$. That union is probably what the OP meant by the cryptic " any circle that has radius $r$ and is separated by distance $d$".

Comment: I added some imagination, I hope it helps